# R count reoccuring instances in a vector

Tags: r

I am looking for an efficient way to convert a vector `v <- c(a,a,a,b,a,b,b,c,b)` into a compressed vector `res <- c(a3,b1,a1,b2,c1,b1)` using R.

{a,b,c} could by also longer, e.g. {alfonso, berta, cesar}.

Comment: You're describing the `rle` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Need both rle and paste0, but first an example in code.:

```
v <- scan(text= "a,a,a,b,a,b,b,c,b", sep=",", what="")
#Read 9 items
 v
[1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "a" "b" "b" "c" "b"
 rle(v)
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:6] 3 1 1 2 1 1
#  values : chr [1:6] "a" "b" "a" "b" "c" "b"
 paste0( rle(v)$values, rle(v)$lengths)
##
[1] "a3" "b1" "a1" "b2" "c1" "b1"
```

Comment: Can also do `Reduce(paste0, rev(rle(v)))`

Comment: Yep. Could drop the rev and use `[2:1]`.

Answer (score 1):

An option can to use `dplyr::lag` to generate output as:

```
#Data
v <- c("a","a","a","b","a","b","b","c","b")
sapply(split(v, cumsum(v!=dplyr::lag(v, default = " "))),
       function(x)paste0(x[1],length(x))) %>% as.vector()
#Result
#[1] "a3" "b1" "a1" "b2" "c1" "b1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're describing [Run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

R provides this as `base::rle`

To create a single string, you can rowbind the two results provided by `rle` (`values` and `lengths`), and collapse them together:

`paste(rbind(rle(v)$values, rle(v)$lengths), collapse="")`